# What do the solid and border colors mean in the damage info?

Tags: mechwarrior-online

On your mech and sufficiently scouted enemy mechs, you get damage readouts like this:
[image]

It looked simple at first, but I'm confused now. What's do the borders and the solid colors inside mean?

Comment: I suspect one means armor the other means actual component hp?

Comment: @spartacus: That's what I was thinking maybe, but I thought that I should confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on how it acts and what repairs would do when they were in, I'm pretty sure that spartacus is correct. The border colors mean that component's armor on that side, and the inner colors mean the internal structure of the component. The colors then go from gray to yellow to orange to red to missing.

Answer (score 1):

The border colour (red is bad) is your armour status and the inside block is your internal structure status.  Internal structure can take hits from front or back so the colours should match up and they do.

Comment: This seems essentially identical to the currently-accepted answer.